# Open an URL in Python

Tags: python, httprequest, urlopen

How can I open an URL with a variable and key values in it in Python?
I tried as below, but I got a 400 bad request. Opening the file (host) in my web browser doesn't seem to be any problem though. Perhaps the proxy?

```
for verb in verbs:
    host = 'http://google.no/blabla?text=' + verb + '&pos=Any'
    checktext = '<font color="maroon">' + verb + '</font>'

    params = {'http': 'http://www.someproxy.com:3128'}

    req = urllib2.Request(host, urllib.urlencode(params))
    res = urllib2.urlopen(req)

    print res.read()
```

**NB: Got it. When I put None in as second argument in req (urllib.urlencode(params)), it works. So, it must be the proxy the server does not like.**

Comment: Have a look at the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library, which makes python HTTP vastly less troublesome.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are doing with `params` there. The second argument to `urllib2.Request` is the data to POST to the server.

The way to set a proxy with `Request` is to call `req.set_proxy(host, type)` - see [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request.set_proxy).

Answer (score 0):

Try using urllib2.build_opener:

```
import urllib2,cookielib

opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookielib.CookieJar()))
url = 'http://google.no/blabla'

for verb in verbs:
    data = '?text=' + verb + '&pos=Any' # not really sure how to fit your 'params' in here
    socket = opener.open(url,data)
    print socket.read()
```